# Html.EditFor Onchange Event

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I am developing an MVC4 application.
I want to change **IsChanged**  field in my Model, when **model.ExternalVenderNo** is changed.

Below are codes on View page

```
 <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ExternalVenderNo, new { @onchange = "OnChangeEvent();" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ExternalVenderNo)
    </div>
```

and

```
 function OnChangeEvent()
{
    alert("value is changed");
    @{ Model.IsChanged = true;
    }
}
```

To check whether **OnChangeEvent** is being called , i put **alert**.
But **alert** is also **not working**.
 it means **OnChangeEvent** is not beign called.

I just want to change **IsChanged**  field to true, when **model.ExternalVenderNo** is changed.

**Model** has `bool IsChanged`

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Try the same with `@Html.TextBoxFor`

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.ExternalVenderNo, new { onchange = "OnChangeEvent()" })

<script type="text/javascript">
 function OnChangeEvent(){
    alert("value is changed");
    @Model.IsChanged = true;
 }
</script>
```

or leave Jquery to handle the change event

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.ExternalVenderNo)

<script type="text/javascript">
$('#ExternalVenderNo').change(function(){
    alert('Changed!');
    @Model.IsChanged = true;
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 13):

Try adding to attributes

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => Model.Lengthofside1, new {  htmlAttributes = new { onchange = "OnChangeEvent(this)", @class = "form -control text-right" } })
```

This worked for me.

Comment: simpler and way easier than selected answer

Comment: you are a champ

Answer (score 6):

The following will definitely work for you.

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
   $('#ExternalVenderNo').on("change", function()
   {
      alert('Changed!');
   });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

try jquery for this

```
$('#ExternalVenderNo').change(function(){
    alert('Changed!');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
                <td>


                    @Html.EditorFor(modelItem => item.mahang,
                        new
                        {
                            htmlAttributes = new
                            {
                                @class = "text",
                                 id = @item.id,
                                 onkeydown = "return  event.keyCode != 13",
                                onChange = "replaceContentsOfDivupdatecodename(**this.id**, this.value)"
                            }
                        })

                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(modelItem => item.mahang)



                </td>
```

> it take me 3 day to find out it, may be it helf ful so some one
> i use this.id to take value and input to fuction script

```
 <script>
function replaceContentsOfDivupdatecodename(idxoa, mahang) {
    $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("AddPaialTransferUpdate", "Home")',
        data: {
            id: "_DetailTransferlist.cshtml",
            mahang: mahang,
            idxoa: idxoa
        },
        type: "POST",
        success: function(data) {
            $('#placeHolderDiv2').html(data);
        }
    });
}
```