# onchange not binding to editorfor mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am having an issue with binding an onChange event to an EditorFor thats being dynamically loaded a dropdown list of countries in a partial view. I have spent a few hours looking for a solution as to what i am doing wrong and why the prop/attribute onChange event is not binding to the div element when the page loads.

The EditorFor block:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-2 labelText">@Html.GetResourceString("BuyNow.Step5", "CountryLabel")</div>`enter code here`
       <div class="col-md-10">
         @Html.EditorFor(m => m.Country, "DropDownSelect", new { DisplayLabel = "empty", List = BaseController.CountryList, CssClass = "tealInput", onChange = "OnChange()" })
      </div>
</div>
```

Now when i view source on the page once its loaded to check if the onChange is present in the div it is not.

Viewed Source after page load:

```
<select class="tealInput" data-bind="value: DefaultBilling.Country" data-val="true" data-val-length="The Country value cannot exceed 50 characters. " data-val-length-max="50" id="DefaultBilling_Country" name="DefaultBilling.Country"><option value="">Select</option>
```

As you can see the onchange isnt present and so far i have not been able to debug the issue. Any information on this and possible resources to go study to find out why this is happening would be greatly appreciated.

I have changed the way I am displaying the dropdown:

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-2 labelText" style="white-space:nowrap;">@Html.GetResourceString("BuyNow.Step5", "CountryLabel")</div>
      <div class="col-md-10">
         <select class="tealInput" name="country" data-bind='value: DefaultBilling.Country' id="ddlCountry_@Model.AddressTypeId" style="text-align:right;" onchange="OnChange()">

               @foreach (var countries in BaseController.CountryList)
               {
                    <option value="@countries.Value">@countries.Text</option>
                }
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Same issue here as well, on my watch its showing OnChange() is unavailable

Comment: Use either `TextBoxFor` or jQuery binding `$("#Country").change(function() { ... });` to bind change event, or use `@` before event name: `@Html.EditorFor(m => m.Country, "DropDownSelect", new { DisplayLabel = "empty", List = BaseController.CountryList, CssClass = "tealInput", @onchange = "OnChangeHideBillingFields()" })` (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19452784/html-editfor-onchange-event).

Comment: why not use TextboxFor?

Comment: TextBoxFor doesnt really work for what im tring to accomplish.I have removed the EditorFor and loaded displayed and loaded my drop down in a different way. I have tried onchange = "onchange()" and using .change on both the Jquery element selector and the document the onChange function is showing up in my watch as unavailable.