# C# - EditorFor functionality of ' onChangeEvent' not working

Tags: javascript, c#, html, jquery, razor

My editorfor onChangeEvent isn't working and I can't figure out why.

here is my javascript function

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    function OnChangeEvent() {
        alert("value is changed");
        var compQty = $('#compQTY').val();
        //do other functions here also like change button
        //if decrease add below
        if (compQty < @Model.comp_qty) {
            btn.Attributes.Add("onclick", "clicked(event)");
        }
    }
<script>
```

and here is my editorFor

```
<div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.comp_qty, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @if (ViewBag.isValid == false)
                {
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.comp_qty, new { disabled = "disabled", @Value = Model.comp_qty, @readonly = "readonly" })
                }
                else
                {
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.comp_qty, new { htmlAttributes = new { onchange = "OnChangeEvent(this)", min = 0, @class = "form-control", @id = "compQTY" } })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.comp_qty, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                }
            </div>
</div>
```

from what I have googled this should work but it is not. Can anybody help me figure out what I'm missing or what the possible solution is?

Comment: It looks like you are constructing your inline binding with `"OnChangeEvent(this)"`, meaning you are going to be passing in the element on the arguments list.  Given that, you do not need jQuery to lookup the value for the element.  Accept in the element on the method parameters, and then just use `thatVariable.value` to get the value.

Comment: When you do `onchange="somefunction(this)"` the `this` is the element that the event is on.  So the logic passes the element into the function.  So to reference that element, you just need to change your method to `function somefunction (myelement) { ... }` to use it

Comment: @Taplar Thanks but I had tried that and it still is not working

Comment: Are there any console errors?  Do any of your alerts work?  "It doesn't work" doesn't really help us figure out what the issue is.

Comment: @Taplar sorry about that, there are no console errors it just simply won't run the onchangefunction when a value is changed

Comment: What kind of tag is being generated?  And just to be clear, you are saying the first alert in your method is not happening?

Comment: yes, I cant even get the alert to work in the function. And what do you mean by 'what kind of tag is generated'? Sorry for my ignorance, I'm just beginning

Comment: Is it generating an <input>, <span>, <div>, etc.  What is it generating?

Comment: Also something I just noticed.  Your `class` and `id` both have `@` in front of them, but your other two attributes do not.

Comment: @Taplar oh it's generating a div I'll update my question to include it

Comment: Try using `@onchange = "OnChangeEvent(this)"` to see if it needs the `@` for the onchange.  Because according to http://dev.beansoftware.com/asp-net-mvc-editorfor-textarea/, that tag should be making a textarea, not a div, which should work with change events.

Comment: @Taplar I added it, still no luck. Really bizzare. Perhaps I misunderstood the tag. I thought you meant what surrounds the editorFor. But how can I see what is generated?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19452784/html-editfor-onchange-event  <= just found that when searching for that asp method

Comment: @Taplar yeah thats what I was looking at and that's what I based my code off, but it isn't working. I can try changing my editorFor to a textboxfor even though editorFor is a lot more convenient. But you will also see in that link some user provide an answer that is the same way I'm doing it now. The answer is from Mark

Comment: @Taplar TextBoxFor isn't even working, must be some type of bug